# trigger a javascript function before on any AJAX call

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

Here, I have a function which needs to be called before any AJAX call present in the .NET project.

Currently, I have to call `checkConnection` on every button click which is going to invoke AJAX method, if net connection is there, proceeds to actual **AJAX** call!
Anyhow, I want to avoid this way and the `checkConnection` function should be called automatically before any AJAX call on the form.

In short, **I want to make function behave like an `event` which will be triggered before any AJAX call**

Adding sample, which makes AJAX call on button click; Of course, after checking internet availability...

```
//check internet availability
function checkConnection() {
    //stuff here to check internet then, set return value in the variable
    return Retval;
}

//Ajax call
function SaveData() {
        var YearData = {
            "holiday_date": D.getElementById('txtYears').value
        };
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'Service1.svc/SaveYears',
            data: JSON.stringify(YearData),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            processData: true,
            success: function (data, status, jqXHR) {
                //fill page data from DB
            },
            error: function (xhr) {
                alert(xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
    }
```

And below is current way to call function:

```
<form onsubmit="return Save();">
    <input type="text" id="txtYears" /><br />
    <input type="submit" id="btnSave" onclick="return checkConnection();" value="Save" />
    <script>
        function Save() {
            if (confirm('Are you sure?')) {
                SaveData();
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    </script>
</form>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot implicitly call a function without actually writing a call even once(!)  in JavaScript.

So, better to call it in actual `AJAX` and for that you can use `beforeSend` property of ajaxRequest like following, hence there will be no need to call `checkConnection()` seperately:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'Service1.svc/SaveYears',
            data: JSON.stringify(YearData),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            processData: true,
            beforeSend: function() {
               if(!checkConnection())
                   return false;
            },
            success: function (data, status, jqXHR) {
                //fill page data from DB
            },
            error: function (xhr) {
                alert(xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
```

It reduces the call that you have made `onsubmit()` of `form` tag!

UPDATE:
to register a global function before every AJAX request use:

```
$(document).ajaxSend(function() {
  if(!checkConnection())
     return false;
});
```

Comment: if its considered as working,still needs to be called in every AJAX

Comment: but if connection returns false , ajax request will not be called @Vikrant

Comment: Yes it is but plz read my question, it is about executing a function without writing a function call whether in other function OR in AJAX!

Comment: Can you check my update .. .ajaxSend will register through all AJAX requests so you do not have to write it in every AJAX request.. @Vikrant

Comment: @BrijeshBhatt : What about if checkConnection() is already contain ajax call? How can we define except at there?

Comment: is it okay to make another ajax call in place of the checkConnection function? will the main ajax call execute after the secondary one here?
$.ajax({
// primary ajax call...
  beforeSend: function() {
    // secondary ajax call here.....
  }
});

Answer (score 2):

The best way is to use a publish-subsribe pattern to add any extra functions to be called on pre-determined times (either before or after ajax for example).

jQuery already supports custom publish-subsrcibe

For this specific example just do this:

```
//Ajax call
function SaveData(element) {
       var doAjax = true; 
       var YearData = {
            "holiday_date": D.getElementById('txtYears').value
        };
        if (element === myForm) 
        {
           doAjax = checkConnection();
        }
        if ( doAjax )
        {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'Service1.svc/SaveYears',
            data: JSON.stringify(YearData),
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            processData: true,
            success: function (data, status, jqXHR) {
                //fill page data from DB
            },
            error: function (xhr) {
                alert(xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
        }
        else
        {
          // display a message
        }
    }
```

Hope i understand correctly what you mean.

UPDATE:

in the `if` you can do an additional check if the function is called from the form or a field (for example add an argument SaveData(element))

If you use the saveData in html, do this: `"saveData(this)"`, maybe you should post your html as well

Comment: I welcome your suggestion but it doesn't make much difference than my method.. `if` is in AJAx instead of function! what if multiple AJAx calls, will you be calling it in every AJAX?

Comment: @Vikrant, ok, but i would suggest to change the title of your question since it does make much sense

Comment: @Vikrant, in the `if` you can do an additional check if the function is called from the form or a field (for example add an argument `SaveData(element)`)

Comment: html is already there in question and what you are saying is already been answered by @BrijeshBhatt

Comment: @Vikrant yeap sorry, use `"Save(this)"` so if the element is set and is the form you know where the function was called from

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
$(document)
.ajaxStart(function () {
  alert("ajax start");
})
.ajaxComplete(function () {
     alert("ajax complete");
})
```

That's it!!

Comment: Thanks but your post talks about function between ajax call; but I needed the way to execute a function before AJAX call

Comment: No @Vikrant, this code is not a part of AJAX call. It is separate code from AJAX call. And add your function in .ajaxStart function. That function will call before any AJAX call in your application.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
beforeSend: function () {
},
```

`ajax` method

Comment: actually not helping :(