# With single AJAX call how to get back multiple objects as a callback data

Tags: arrays, json, ajax, object, symfony

I have ajax post method to  the controller by the server side, searching in  entities. I have a bit trouble with this thing because I can actually send multiple objects but I don't have a clue how to parse them.

```
 $serializer = $this->container->get('serializer');
    $reports = $serializer->serialize($cables, 'json');
    $reports1 = $serializer->serialize($contacts, 'json');
    return new JsonResponse (array($reports1, $reports));
```

This is how I send multiple objects:
and How I'm trying to read them:

```
function (data)
{   var obj =  JSON.parse(data);
    console.log(obj);
    $('#resposeText').val(obj[1].description); }
```

Basically I', receiving two arrays, or I don't what the hell I'm receiving but it doesn't work.

Also getting the famous error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token , in JSON at position 1306

```
   return new JsonResponse ($reports);
```

Sending only one object there are now problems.
Can someone explain to me how it's supposed to be done?

Comment: Please format your code properly.

Comment: [this might help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29489243/trigger-a-javascript-function-before-on-any-ajax-call) you

Answer (score 1):

I have manage to answer it!!

Ok, the problem however was very simple to be honest.

First the two object must be send in array as I did in the controller, but the trick is in Jquery,

```
 function (data)
                     {
                         obj1 = data[0];
                         obj2 = data[1];

                          var obj =  JSON.parse(obj2);
                          var obj1 =  JSON.parse(obj1);

                         console.log(obj[1].description); }
```

That is how the object ca be parsed.... Hope this will help how future :D

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken, your `data` is already `JS` `Array` - you don't need to convert it once more. Another thing is that you probably overlooked is that `stringify` converts `array`/`object` to `string`. That said, you cannot do: `"some_string"[1].description` - that just does not make sense. Most probably, you wanted to use `JSON.parse()` call.

I had a similar issue some time ago, where my code did the `$.parseJSON()` from `jQuery`.

Try doing `console.log(data);`. It should already be array of two elements (due to `application/json` mime type from `JsonResponse`).

Also, very important, do not return plain arrays **ever** unless you want to be hacked. There is a documented `CSRF` **[attack vector](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/20/anatomy-of-a-subtle-json-vulnerability.aspx/)**

Comment: yep, You are totaly right it has to be "parse", but indeed the problem is that I want to sent two different object, the only way that I come up is to send them in a JsonResponce(array($data1, $data2)); which is converting them in array again and I receive the error mentioned above.

Comment: Did you try removing the `parse` part and just printing the `data`?